# ArcGIS not finding newly installed toolbar (.dll, .tlb files?)

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, toolbar, dll

I'm trying to use a toolbar that was developed by the EPA for BMP siting (see below link). The download seems like it should be fairly straightforward, an executable (BMPSitingTool_Setup.msi) is run and the toolbar is downloaded to the Program Files x86 folder within my C-drive. The BMP siting tool comes with a host of .dll, .tlb, .olb, etc files. According to the installation instructions, once I open a new ArcGIS map, it should find this new toolbar automatically and it should show up under Customize > Customize Mode. It doesn't. I've tried doing "add from file" and manually selecting the .tlb file but I get a message of "can't load type library from specified file" followed by "no new objects added". Any idea what's causing this? I'm on ArcGIS 10.3 and the tool was developed within ArcGIS 10.1, but I didn't think there were any compatibility issues with later versions of ArcGIS.

Edit: I've verified that I have administrator privileges on my computer.

https://www.epa.gov/water-research/best-management-practices-bmps-siting-tool

Comment: I downloaded it, ran the install and it all worked OK for me, I am using a clean install of 10.4.1. I can see the toolbar and it activates when I load their sample data. My gut feeling is that it's a permission thing? Not sure what you can do.

Comment: That's really frustrating. Not sure how to fix it if it's a permission issue..

Comment: You might turn off the User Account Control, install and add the toolbar and then turn the UAC back on.  I faintly recall also having to run ArcMap as an administrator to add a dll once.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually registering the dll. The double quotes are needed because of spaces in the paths. The following is a single command.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ESRIRegAsm.exe" /P:desktop "C:\Program Files (x86)\BMP Siting Tool\ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.dll"

Comment: It said Registration failed, the system cannot find the file specified. I verified that the .dll is within the exact same folder location as is within the command script.

Comment: Maybe the command did not copy/paste correctly. You can manually enter the command in a cmd window.

Comment: Nope still doesn't work :( this is really frustrating.. I've installed toolbars before with ArcGIS and not had this issue. I think I'm following the directions exactly... I create the folder on my C-drive, unzip the download to that folder, run the .msi executable, open ArcGIS....

Answer (score 1):

The way I was able to add the BMP Siting Toolbar was by clicking the "Add From File" button under ArcMap's Customize box and then opening the .dll diles from the C:\SUSTAIN\ETC folder.